# Saving objects with hibernate and JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm fairly new to Hibernate world and therefore would like to ask some clarifications about saving objects in hibernate.

Let's assume that we have an object, which has nested objects, so said relationships to another objects.

```
// Main object I would like to save
@Entity
public class A {
 private Long id;
 private String name;
 private B type; // Has only specific one type from another table
 private C anotherType; // Has only specific anotherType from another table
}

// Several type B in database table
@Entity
public class B {}

// Several type C in database table
@Entity
public class C {}
```

Now let's assume that when POST request comes in I should get a DTO which contains information for saving this class A into database, but it has nested objects like B and C.
How does this saving to database work then? I mean should I have the whole B and C objects in DTO already and then converting all of them to entities for saving? Or should I have only id values (C id and B id), then querying the specific repository, getting entities, setting them into A through setters and then saving?

So my main question is how is it most efficient to save data in that case?

Comment: It depends. If the goal is to create an A and also its B and its C, then the DTO needs to contain everything. If B and C already exist and you just want to create an A, then the DTO should only contain the IDs of B and C. And you should get them (or get a reference to them, if you don't want to check that they exist before saving A).

Comment: It's the second option that B and C both exist already in the database. In that case it means if I have ID values for both B and C, then I have to query them before? If I understand correctly, then A would have OneToOne relation with B and C.

Comment: A would have a OneToOne association to B if only one instance of A can reference a given B. I.e. if B is owned by one A and only one A. If not, it would be a ManyToOne. You need to get a B using find() (that would actually load the B from the database, checking that it actually exists), or to get a reference to B using... getReference() (that would assume that the B exists, without loading anything from the database).